# Speed up reducing size of large JPEG image using ImageMagick

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, image-resizing, imagemagick-convert

I have a very large JPEG image (10800x7497) that I want to resize down to 50% of its resolution. I have already reduced the image colors down to 64 colors using `-define jpeg:colors=64`, but when I try resizing the image, ImageMagick takes very long to process the image, probably 20 minutes or more (since I have stopped the process when no output image is saved within 20 minutes, although Task Manager shows ImageMagick processing the image). How can I speed up the resizing of this large image? I have tried the following codes but still it takes too long:

```
magick -define jpeg:size=10800x7500 "image1.jpg" -resize 5400x3750 "image1-resized.jpg"

magick -define jpeg:size=5400x3750 "image1.jpg" -resize 5400x3750 "image1-resized.jpg"

magick -depth 5 "image1.jpg" -resize 50% "image1-resized.jpg"
```

Comment: Try running `magick identify -version` to see if you have Q8 or Q16. If you have Q16, you could try installing/building the Q8 version to reduce the memory pressure. If you have an SSD available, with NTFS filesystem, you could point the **ImageMagick** temporary path environment variable at that for faster disk access.

Comment: Or you could install `libvips` and probably do it in a fraction of the time.

Comment: Resizing an image that size (filled with random noise) runs in 6 CPU seconds (10 seconds elapsed with SSD) on my PC (Core I5). 20 minutes is a lot even if swapping on a slow disk. What says your system monitor about the IM process(es)? What memory? I/O rate? What is the disk activity? Note that the best way to reduce the output size is to blur the image, as far as I can tell reducing the color count increases the final size. You can also change the compression quality and the chroma subsampling.

Comment: If you want to try with `libvips`, you could use `vipsthumbnail big.jpg -s 5400 -o small.jpg` That uses 220MB peak memory on my machine, whereas **ImageMagick** uses nearly 2GB and 1.6s instead of 6s.

Comment: Check your Imagemagick RAM resources and increase them if you can in the policy.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your imagemagick is swapping to disc. You probably need to adjust your `policy.xml`.

This is the file containing the limits for the amount of memory and disc magick is allowed to use. The [magick docs have some notes](https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php), but check `/etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.xml` and have a look for lines like eg.:

```
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="256MiB"/>
```

256mb memory use is far too small -- change it something like:

```
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="8GiB"/>
```

You'll see quite a few other similar lines, adjust them to fit your hardware.

I would simply use `resize`. The `-define` hint will turn on jpeg shrink-on-load, which will lose quality and cause (probably) noticeable moire fringing. Plus for a 50% shrink there's no speed benefit.

```
$ identify big.jpg
big.jpg JPEG 10800x7497 10800x7497+0+0 8-bit sRGB 13.4733MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e convert big.jpg -resize 5400x3750 x.jpg
1130340:0.92
```

So 0.92s and 1.1gb of memory with imagemagick6. imagemagick7 is usually about half the speed and twice the memory use, so I'd expect about 2s and 2GB.

As Mark says, [`vipsthumbnail`](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) is likely to be quicker. I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e vipsthumbnail big.jpg -s 5400 -o x.jpg
295460:0.69
```

So 300mb of memory and 0.7s. This PC has a stupid number of cores (32!) and you really can't get that much parallelism out of basic JPEG shrinking, so you see a useful speedup and lower memory use if you turn the number of threads down:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e vipsthumbnail big.jpg -s 5400 -o x.jpg --vips-concurrency=3
77744:0.43
```

78mb of memory and 0.43s.

Comment: Very good recommendation, `vipsthumbnail` does really fast. `ImageMagick` was just stuck at the downsizing of a 25000 px image while consuming 5 gigabytes of ram. `vipsthumbnail` did it with 70 megabytes of ram.